# variables pre-evaluation in loop range spliting

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I would like to multithread a for loop but I have some variable inside my loop what need to know the previous state.
Well it's not quite easy to explain.

Here is an exemple :

```
    double mu1 = 0, q1 = 0;
    double max_sigma = 0, max_val = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        double p_i, q2, mu2, sigma;
        p_i = h[i]*scale;
        mu1 *= q1;
        q1 += p_i;
        q2 = 1. - q1;

        if(std::min(q1,q2) < FLT_EPSILON || std::max(q1,q2) > 1. -FLT_EPSILON )
            continue;

        mu1 = (mu1 + i*p_i)/q1;
        mu2 = (mu - q1*mu1)/q2;
        sigma = q1*q2*(mu1 - mu2)*(mu1 - mu2);
        if( sigma > max_sigma )
        {
            max_sigma = sigma;
            max_val = i;
        }
    }
```

`scale` is a `double` scalar value.

`h` is a `std::vector<std::uint64_t>`

If I split the range in sevral part for process any sub range I can locally (in each thread) compute first `p_i`.

But I don't see how I could determine the value  `mu1`.

So my question is : Is there any way to determine `mu1` at the begining of a thread for a range B without prior of the result of `mu1` what have been processed in a thread for a range A?
If yes, how?

Comment: what is your goal in multi-threading the loop?  if performance, you will probably be better off focusing on auto-vectorizing the loop instead, since the overhead of managing threads will probably negate any benefit of running across multiple cores for this relatively simple arithmetic.  also note that in addition to mu1 (and undefined mu? used in mu2's computation), max_sigma and max_val require special handling to avoid a race condition between threads.

Comment: Hello Matt.
I even know how to vectorize by myself the loop.
I would to know if there is a way in such situation to do an efficient multithreading... or not.

Comment: Efficient parallelization is rather difficult if the computation of element `i` somehow depends on element `i-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the code shown it seems difficult to achieve much with a multi-threaded solution. The problem is that `mu1` and `q1` depends on the values from the previous loop so you can't really carry on before the previous loop is complete.

If you code was more like:

```
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    SomeComplexAndSlowCalculation(); // Not depending on mu1 and q1

    mu1 = mu1 * ....;
    q1 = q1 + ....;

    SomeOtherComplexAndSlowCalculation(); // Depending on mu1 and q1
                                          // but not changing them

}
```

you could use `std::condition_variable` something like this:

```
    SomeComplexAndSlowCalculation(); // Not depending on mu1 and q1

    cv_previous.wait(...);  // wait for thread handling previous index to complete

    mu1 = mu1 * ....;
    q1 = q1 + ....;

    cv_next.notify_one(); // tell thread handling next index to carry on

    SomeOtherComplexAndSlowCalculation(); // Depending on mu1 and q1
                                          // but not changing them
```

You would have to launch a new thread for each index.

For this to make any difference/improvement, the two functions must be pretty slow.

Comment: Hello 4386427.
That what I thought.
I investigate some similar approach during the week end.
The processing time show me I was ten time slower than the sequential processing.
Thank for your answer :).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that parallelism will result in a speed improvement, but the way you would accomplish this is to algebraically reduce your computations to be based on the absolute value of i rather than the previous state (i-1), so e.g. replace

```
p_1 = h[i]*scale;
mu1 *= q1;
q1 += p_1;

mu1 = product_n(pre_scaled_h, 0, i-1);
q1 = sum_n(pre_scaled_h, 0, i);
```

Where h[] is pre-scaled to simplify the operations on it, and product_n and sum_n are defined to compute the corresponding product and sum of elements in pre-scaled h from 0 to the corresponding third parameter inclusive (note that mu1 is based in i-1 rather than i, because it is multiplied by q1 before q1 is recomputed).

This algebraic reduction will eliminate the dependency on the previous iteration, and should be possible for all variables except max_sigma and max_val, which will probably have to be computed on each separate thread and then the corresponding set of thread maximums will have to be compared to find the real maximum.  A traditional lock on these will likely eliminate any possible speed increase, so handling that will require carefully managing the threads yourself (since e.g. concurrency::parallel_for doesn't guarantee which block of work will run on a given thread).

Note that you should be able to reduce this to a single computation rather than an iterative loop (of course, with simple sum/product operations on h), since the algebraic reduction appears to be based entirely on h[].  If you can reduce it to a single equation without an iterative loop, you will gain more performance than any other option.

Comment: Matt Thank you very much for this answer :).
I'll investigate this.